# Undefined property: stdClass::$Prestador_Seguro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Me salta el siguiente error al querer ingresar a la vista edit, por lo que pude investigar y si no estoy equivocado, creo que tiene algo que ver con un array, pero no logro encontrar la solución.

**Undefined property: stdClass::$Prestador_Seguro**

En la vista edit.blade tengo lo siguiente

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Prestador de Salud</label>
                <select name="Prestador_Seguro" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($prestadores as $pre)
                    @if ($pre->Prestador_Seguro==$pmedicamento->Prestador_Seguro)
                       <option value="{{$pre->Nombre}}" selected>{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                       @else
                        <option value="{{$pre->Nombre}}">{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                       @endif
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

En la parte de edit en el controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $pmedicamento=PMedicamentos::findOrFail($id);

        $departamentos = DB::table('departamentos')->get();

        $medicamentosp = DB::table('medicamentos')->where('condicion','=','1')->get();

        $prestadores = DB::table('prestadorseguro')->get();

        $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

        $solicitud = DB::table('tiposolicitud')->get();

        return view("PMedicamentos.edit", [
            "pmedicamento"=>$pmedicamento,
            "departamentos" => $departamentos,
            "medicamentos" => $medicamentosp,
            "prestadores" => $prestadores,
            "laboratorios" => $laboratorios,
            "solicitud" => $solicitud
        ]);
    }
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Cuál es tu modelo Prestador? Puedes agregar el código por favor?

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado Prestador no tiene modelo, el modelo en esta sección digamos es PMedicamentos. lo de Prestador_Seguro es un dato que sale de una tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: Ya veo, cuál es tu archivo de migración o tu DLL de la tabla prestadores?

Comment: El DLL vendría a ser el nombre de la tabla en la  base de datos? me fije en el archivo de migración y se llama Prestador/Seguro, yo le había cambiado el nombre posteriormente pero alli no y quedo así como está.

Comment: El DDL es el archivo que puede describir la estructura de tu tabla. Lo que necesitamos ver es exactamente qué nombres de columnas tienes en tu tabla... ese es el error que te está mandando, que no existe en prestadores o en pmedicamento una columna que se llame Prestador_Seguro

Comment: Y si pruebo cambiando el nombre a Prestador_Seguro en todos los lugares donde aparece en el DDL puede solucionarse digamos? o ya no se puede modificar ese archivo?

Comment: Sinceramente es bastante extraña (en mi opinión) la forma como haces uso de la base de datos y la ausencia casi total de modelos. Laravel te ofrece muchas herramientas para hacer todo esto realmente sencillo.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**$pmedicamento** no tiene la propiedad, eso pasa cuando el objeto no tiene la propiedad.

```
$pmedicamento = PMedicamentos::findOrFail($id);
```

Debería tener la propiedad dentro del objeto, sí usas Lavarel, puede definir los atributos:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#default-attribute-values

Otra opción es usar un mutador:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators